# Check if multiple records exist with ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Using `#exists?` gives a false positive (i.e. will return true) when at least one of the keys exist.

```
MyModel.exist?(key: [:risk_score, :i_made_this_up]) # => true
```

For a small number of checks I could do:

```
[:risk_score, :i_made_this_up].all? { |key| MyModel.exists?(key: key) }
```

But this is an N+1 query, what if I have many keys to check?

Comment: If all you care about is `exists?` then you could also go with `MyModel.where(key: keys).distinct.count == keys.uniq.size`

Comment: `MyModel.where(key: keys)` is an unnecessary IMO `select * from ...`. Prefer `ids` or any other.

Comment: @SebastianPalma Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean, I'm not using `#where`.

Comment: Missed the @engineersmnky tag ;)

Comment: @SebastianPalma not sure what you mean. If I have a list of `keys` and what to make sure they all exist but do not care which ones do or don't exist then I need to count the distinct rows for those keysand compare it to the count of my list. However there is a flaw in what I posted and it should be `MyModel.where(key: keys).distinct(:key).count == keys.uniq.size`

Answer (score 2):

You can subtract the possible keys away from the given keys and the result should be an empty array:

```
  unknown_keys = keys - MyModel.pluck(:key)
  raise(ArgumentError, "one or more keys do not exist: #{unknown_keys.join(', ')}") unless unknown_keys.empty?
```

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way of doing what you are asking is to do a `COUNT(DISTINCT key)` on your table which would translate in ActiveRecord like so:

```rb
target_keys = [:risk_score, :i_made_this_up]
MyModel.select(:key).where(key: target_keys).distinct.count == target_keys.length
# In SQL would give  =>
# SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "my_models"."key") FROM "my_models" WHERE "my_models"."status" IN ($1, $2)  [["key", "risk_score"], ["key", "i_made_this_up"]]
```

This way you perform only one database query that should be very efficient as well especially if there is a DB index on `key` column.